# Jqgrid - How to display information in a textbox by row selected on a grid

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I'm quite new to php and jquery so any help would be much appreciated. I basically have a grid called 'booking' which displays all the information about bookings stored in a database.

[image]

When you double click a row it brings up a Jquery Dialog Box that displays all the information about their booking:

[image]

At the moment, no matter which booking you click on it always displays the information from the first row of the database. What I want is for it to display the data from the database by which row is selected.

This is the PHP code:

```
        $pdo = new SQL();
        $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);

        try {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM tblbookings";


            $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);

            $stmt->execute();

            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

 /*           Company::set_id($row['Id']);
            Company::set_name($row['CompName']); */
            BookingDocket::set_id($row['id']);
            BookingDocket::set_bookref($row['bookref']);
            BookingDocket::set_returndate($row['returndate']);


            $stmt->closeCursor();

        }

        catch (PDOException $pe) {
            die("Error: " .$pe->getMessage(). " Query: ".$stmt->queryString);
        }

        $dbh = null;

    }
```

JQGrid Code:

```
$("#bookings").jqGrid({
    url:'scripts/php/bootstrp/cp.request.php?ft=gg&table=bookings&showindex=0',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['id', 'Booking Reference','Date of Booking','Time of Booking','Fare'],
    colModel :[{name:'id', index:'id', hidden:'true', align:'center', search:false, width:'210px'},
    {name:'bookref', index:'bookref', align:'center', search:true, width:'210px'},
        {name:'recordeddate', index:'recordeddate', align:'center', search:false, width:'210px'},
        {name:'recordedtime', index:'recordedtime', align:'center', search:false, width:'210px'},
        {name:'fare', index:'fare', align:'center', search:false, width:'210px'}],
    pager: $('#bookingsPager'), rowNum:500, rowList:[500,2000,5000,10000],
    sortname: 'recordeddate',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
hidegrid: false,
rowNum: 500,
    imgpath: 'lib/themes/steel/images',
    height: '300px',
    forceFit: true,
    caption: 'Bookings History',
    loadtext: 'Loading',
    loadui:'enable',
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
    {
        var rowData = new Array();
        rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);
    $("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({ hide: 'slide', height: 625, width: 733, title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ rowData['bookref'] });
    },
    editurl: 'scripts/php/bootstrp/cp.request.php?ft=ug&table=bookings'
}).navGrid("#bookingsPager",{refresh:true,search:true,add:false,edit:false,del:false});

$("#bookings").setGridWidth('710px',false);
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it would be much more easy to include all booking information in the grid as hidden columns and to use [viewGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#viewgridrow) method to display detailed information. To make the hidden columns be visible in the View-form you need add `editrules: { edithidden: true }` setting in the column definition.

I made [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ViewFormOnDoubleclick.htm) for you which uses

```
ondblClickRow: function (id) {
    $(this).jqGrid('viewGridRow', id, { caption: "Booking Reference" });
}
```

As the result the grid with a few columns

[image]

will display the detailed information after the double-click or after selection a row and clicking on the "View" navigator button:

[image]

I think it would be the easiest way to implement your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for this, is there not a way of doing this where I could add a WHERE clause to the SQL statement which would select row by the ID of the hidden row on the JQDialog. Then having the ID posted to the hidden textbox in the JQDialog box by which row is selected if that makes sense

Comment: @user1128694: Of cause one can to do this, but you have to write much more JavaScript code. The problem is that your current code and the Screenshort of the jQuery UI Dialog show that you are beginner in jQuery UI and jqGrid. If you would load no hidden details in the grid like I suggested you can load the grid a little more quickly, but the loading of every "detailed" dialog will be slowly. So I recommend you just load **all** details in the hidden rows of jqGrid and use "View" dialog to show details. I recommend you additionally include `gridview: true` option in the jqGrid.

Comment: @user1128694: Remarks to your code: you can remove unneeded `id` column (the `id` will be saved in the `id` of the `<tr>` elements of the grid if you fill correct the input XML data, see [the documentation] (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#xml_data)), remove second usage of `rowNum:500`, use numbers for `width` and `height` (`width:210` instead of `width:'210px'`), remove `imgpath` parameter, You can additionally improve the performance of the grid if you would use JSON instead of XML for the communication with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need implement method ondblClickRow for get diferent rows:

```
ondblClickRow: function(rowid)
    {
        var rowData = new Array();
        rowData = $("#bookings").getRowData(rowid);
    // Here put the rowid values into the dialog div:
    $("#cp-bookings-dialog").html("Booking date: " + rowData['bookingDate'] + " ... ");
    $("#cp-bookings-dialog").dialog({ hide: 'slide', height: 625, width: 733, title: 'Booking Reference: - '+ rowData['bookref'] });
    }
```

Note: Put into html() all the tag for get a similar format as the picture.